# Check for nil and nil interface in Go

Tags: go

Currently I'm using this helper function to check for nil and nil interfaces

```
func isNil(a interface{}) bool {
  defer func() { recover() }()
  return a == nil || reflect.ValueOf(a).IsNil()
}
```

Since `reflect.ValueOf(a).IsNil()` panics if the value's Kind is anything other than `Chan`, `Func`, `Map`, `Ptr`, `Interface` or `Slice`, I threw in the deferred `recover()` to catch those.

Is there a better way to achieve this check? It think there should be a more straight forward way to do this.

Comment: I don't understand... Why doesn't a simple `a==nil` work?

Comment: @SongGao: there are 2 different things the OP is checking: 1) if `a` is the nil interface itself (in which case `a==nil` will be true), or if `a` is a non-nil interface whose underlying value is a `nil` value of channel, function, pointer, or slice type (in which case `a==nil` will be false)

Comment: The accepted answer is not correct, I was stuck with the same problem. The right answer is to check every case, unfortunately. https://medium.com/@mangatmodi/go-check-nil-interface-the-right-way-d142776edef1

Answer (score 47):

See for example Kyle's answer in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/wnH302gBa4I/discussion) at the golang-nuts mailing list.

In short: If you never store `(*T)(nil)` in an interface, then you can reliably use comparison against nil, no need to use reflection. On the other hand, assigning untyped nil to an interface is always OK.

Comment: what about `[]T(nil)`, `map[T]T(nil)`, `func()(nil)`, and `chan T(nil)`?

Comment: This looks like a nefarious bug waiting to happen.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, can you explain further what means 'On the other hand, assigning untyped nil to an interface is always OK.' i wonder what that means.. for start, i don't know that nil could be typed or untyped... i believe that it is (nil) an special value for any pointer types

Comment: @Victor they just mean that you can store nil in an interface variable.  Such as: `var thing interface{}; thing = nil`.  That is completely legal. `thing` has a "type" of `interface{}`, but does not have an _underlying_ type.  However, you cannot store nil in an untyped variable, like `thing := nil`.  Nil is "typed" in that it requires some kind of type to go along with it.  Like a nil int pointer, or nil string pointer.  You cannot just have a nil pointer to some unknown type without it being an interface.  But then, it's kind of typed... It's definitely confusing.

Comment: @NathanLutterman thanks your explanation, i get the concept. Still is confusing becase nil is a value not a type (outside golang world at least...). Instaed of "untyped nil" i would propose to use the words "literal nil" as is the value itself placed within a expression, instead of the value placed inside one variable, constanst or function call return value.

Comment: You can't always enforce that `nil` is not stored in an interface. Think 3rd party libraries and JSON decoding.

Comment: It is very easy to run into this by accident, even in your everyday logging code. Example: https://go.dev/play/p/9dk3Ad6PS7P

Answer (score 33):

If neither of the earlier options works for you, the best I could came up so far is:

```
if c == nil || (reflect.ValueOf(c).Kind() == reflect.Ptr && reflect.ValueOf(c).IsNil())
```

At least it detects (*T)(nil) cases.

Comment: Works as long as `c` is not a typed pointer to a slice etc. In that case, a logic like `reflect.Ptr(reflect.ValueOf(c)) && reflect.ValueOf(c).Elem().IsNil()` is required. And I doubt with that all addional cases are covered then ...

Answer (score 10):

Two solutions NOT using reflection:

Copy and paste code into editor at: https://play.golang.org/ to see in action.

1. Add an "IsInterfaceNil()" function to interface.
2. Use A "type switch"

**Example 1: IsInterfaceNil()**

```
//:Example #1:
//:I prefer this method because the 
//:TakesInterface function does NOT need to know
//:about all the different implementations of
//:the interface.
package main;
import "fmt";

func main()(){

    var OBJ_OK *MyStruct = &( MyStruct{} );
    var NOT_OK *MyStruct = nil;
    
    //:Will succeed:
    TakesInterface( OBJ_OK );
    
    //:Will fail:
    TakesInterface( NOT_OK );

}

func TakesInterface( input_arg MyInterface ){

    if( input_arg.IsInterfaceNil() ){
        panic("[InputtedInterfaceIsNil]");
    }
    
    input_arg.DoThing();
}

type MyInterface interface{
    DoThing()()
    IsInterfaceNil()(bool)
}
type MyStruct struct{}
func(f *MyStruct)DoThing()(){
    fmt.Println("[MyStruct.DoThing]");
}
func(f *MyStruct)IsInterfaceNil()(bool){
    if(nil==f){ return true; }
    return false;
}
```

**Example 2: Type Switch**

```
//:Example #2:
//:This will also work, but the function taking
//:the interface needs to know about all 
//:implementations. This defeats a bit of the
//:decoupling from implementation that an
//:interface offers, but if you are just using
//:interfaces for polymorphism, it's probably
//:an okay way to go. (opinion)
package main;
import "fmt";

func main()(){

    //:Will succeed:
    var OBJ_OK *IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_01 = 
             &( IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_01{} );
    TakesInterface( OBJ_OK );
    
    //:Will fail:
    var NOT_OK *IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_01 = nil;
    TakesInterface( NOT_OK );
}

func TakesInterface( hasDoThing MyInterface ){

    //:THIS WILL NOT WORK:
    if(nil==hasDoThing){
        panic("[This_Error_Message_Will_Never_Happen]");
    }
    
    //:TYPE SWITCH TO THE RESCUE:
    switch v := hasDoThing.(type){
    
        case (*IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_01): 
        if(nil==v){ panic("[Nil_PTR_01]"); }
        
        case (*IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_02): 
        if(nil==v){ panic("[Nil_PTR_02]"); }
        
        case (*IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_03): 
        if(nil==v){ panic("[Nil_PTR_03]"); }
        
        default: 
            panic("[UnsupportedInterface]");
    }
    
    hasDoThing.DoThing();
    
}

type IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_01 struct{};
type IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_02 struct{};
type IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_03 struct{};
func (f *IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_01)DoThing()(){
    fmt.Println( "DoingTheThing_01" );
}
func (f *IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_02)DoThing()(){
    fmt.Println( "DoingTheThing_02" );
}
func (f *IMPLMENTS_INTERFACE_03)DoThing()(){
    fmt.Println( "DoingTheThing_03" );
}

type MyInterface interface{
    DoThing()()
}
```

Update:
After implementing in my code base, I found #2 (type switch) to be best solution. Specifically because I DON'T want to EDIT the glfw.Window struct in the bindings library I am using. Here is a paste-bin of my use-case.
Apologies for my non-standard coding style. https://pastebin.com/22SUDeGG

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for plain interface{}, which is what the question is about

Comment: I agree. 

It's a workaround. I wasn't happy with the accepted answer of "In short: [ ... ] never store (*T)(nil) in an interface"

Answer (score 4):

For Golang 1.16+

```
func IsNilish(val any) bool {
    if val == nil {
        return true
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(val)
    k := v.Kind()
    switch k {
    case reflect.Chan, reflect.Func, reflect.Map, reflect.Pointer,
        reflect.UnsafePointer, reflect.Interface, reflect.Slice:
        return v.IsNil()
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the interface definition for this exmaple solution:

```
package checker

import (
    "errors"

    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
)

var (
    // ErrNilChecker returned if Check invoked on a nil checker
    ErrNilChecker = errors.New("attempted Check with nil Checker")

    // ErrNilLogger returned if the Check function is provide a nil logger
    ErrNilLogger = errors.New("nil logger provided for Check")
)

// Checker defines the interface
type Checker interface {
    Check(logger *zerolog.Logger) error
}
```

One of our Checker implementations supports aggregation of Checkers.  But testing uncovered the same issue as this thread.
This solution uses the `reflect` package if the simple nil check fails, leveraging the `reflect.Value` type to resolve the question.

```
// AggregateChecker implements the Checker interface, and
//  supports reporting the results of applying each checker
type AggregateChecker struct {
    checkers []Checker
}

func (ac *AggregateChecker) Add(aChecker Checker) error {
    if aChecker == nil {
        return ErrNilChecker
    }

    // It is possible the interface is a typed nil value
    // E.g. checker := (&MyChecker)(nil)
    t := reflect.TypeOf(aChecker)
    if reflect.ValueOf(aChecker) == reflect.Zero(t) {
        return ErrNilChecker
    }

    ac.checkers = append(ac.checkers, aChecker)
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a comprehensive solution this would be a perfect one
Adopted from https://github.com/thoas/go-funk

```golang
// IsEmpty returns if the object is considered as empty or not.
func IsEmpty(obj interface{}) bool {
    if obj == nil || obj == "" || obj == false {
        return true
    }

    for _, v := range numericZeros {
        if obj == v {
            return true
        }
    }

    objValue := reflect.ValueOf(obj)

    switch objValue.Kind() {
    case reflect.Map:
        fallthrough
    case reflect.Slice, reflect.Chan:
        return objValue.Len() == 0
    case reflect.Struct:
        return reflect.DeepEqual(obj, ZeroOf(obj))
    case reflect.Ptr:
        if objValue.IsNil() {
            return true
        }

        obj = redirectValue(objValue).Interface()

        return reflect.DeepEqual(obj, ZeroOf(obj))
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to AH.Pooladvand's answer, but only check if it is `nil`.

```golang
func IsNil(input interface{}) bool {
    if input == nil {
        return true
    }
    kind := reflect.ValueOf(input).Kind()
    switch kind {
    case reflect.Ptr, reflect.Map, reflect.Slice, reflect.Chan:
        return reflect.ValueOf(input).IsNil()
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, here's a reference to the go FAQ explaining why nil interface checks don't work as expected:

https://go.dev/doc/faq#nil_error

An (unusual) workaround which *might* be useful if you have a bunch of pointer types all implementing the same interface ( though it doesn't help for the question of bare `interface{}`s )... use generics to wrap the pointers with a helper:

```golang
// helper struct to track whether an implementation was nil
type SomeRef struct {
    SomeInterface
    IsNil bool
}

// generic helper to create the struct
func Ref[P any,
    I interface {
        *P
        SomeInterface
    }](in *P) SomeRef {
    return SomeRef{I(in), in == nil}
}

// function takes "refs" not the raw interfaces
func DoSomething(refs ...SomeRef) {
    for _, el := range refs {
        // tests for nil...
        if !el.IsNil {
            el.CallSomeInterfaceFunction()
        }
    }
}

// assuming A, B, and C pointers all implement SomeInterface....
func Example(a* A, b *B, c *C) {
    // you can pass refs so the callee can test for nil
    DoSomething(Ref(a), Ref(b), Ref(c))
}
```

an example program here:

https://go.dev/play/p/Q6rNlM2KiVm

Answer (score -1):

May be you try use an error in the function that populates the interface:

package a

```
func getObj() (obj *someObject, err error) {
   obj = db.getA()
   if obj == nil {
      err = fmt.Errorf("Some error")
   }
   return
}
```

package b

```
import a

var i interface{}

i, err = a.getObj()
if err != nil {
   // catch err
} else {
   // do next step
}
```

Answer (score -2):

consider `inboundData` to be your interface

use the `len()` function to check if there are data in the interface

```
if inboundData != nil && len(inboundData) > 0 {
    // ... do stuff | data is present
} else {
    // ... data is not present
}
```

Comment: 1.) This does not work with `interfaces{}`. I suppose `inboundData` is a slice or a map in your case.
2.) It does not tell when something is `nil` and when a map or slice is just empty.
3.) For maps and slices there's no need at all to do an `nil`-check before `len(...)` if you want just to know whether there's data or not. Just do `len(...)` in that case.