# Golang pass nil value as an interface through reflection

Tags: go, reflection

I have a function with interface argument:

```
func f(e error) {
    if e == nil {
        fmt.Println("YEY! NIL") // how to get here?
    } else {
        fmt.Println("NOT NIL :(")
    }
}
```

How do I pass it a nil value via `reflect` so that it passes `== nil` check?

Approach 1:

```
func main() {
    rf := reflect.ValueOf(f)

    nilArg := reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf((error)(nil))) // panic: reflect: Zero(nil)

    rf.Call([]reflect.Value{nilArg})
}
```

Approach 2:

```
type MyError struct{}
func (e MyError) Error() string {
    return ""
}

func main() {
    rf := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    nilArg := reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(&MyError{})) // NOT NIL :(

    rf.Call([]reflect.Value{nilArg})
}
```

Second approach doesn't work due to https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/V0bMSPcCKI

Comment: why  `  rf := reflect.ValueOf(f)` is it a requirement  ? `&MyError{}` is not nil anyways

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the expression `reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()` to get the reflect.Type for interface `error`.

The first approach in the question does not work because the expression `reflect.TypeOf((error)(nil))` returns `nil`.  The concrete type of a nil interface value is nil.

The trick is to pass a non-interface value to `reflect.TypeOf()` and use reflect methods to get the desired `reflect.Type` from there.  In this answer, I pass a `*error` to `reflect.TypeOf()` and call `Elem` on the result to get the `reflect.Type` for `error`.

Use the following to create `nilArg`:

```
nilArg := reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem())
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/XVVfToNAt2)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, basically `e` in the arguments to function `f` is `(*MyError)(nil)` not `nil`. So either assert the interface back to type `MyError` or use more reflection to check if it's nil.

```
e.(*MyError) == nil
```

or

```
reflect.ValueOf(e).IsNil()
```

**Runnable Example**: https://play.golang.org/p/2KWguSx618

useful links:

- [Check for nil and nil interface in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476349/check-for-nil-and-nil-interface-in-go)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/wnH302gBa4I/discussion

Comment: valuable info, however the question is about passing the `nil` argument, not changing the check inside the function

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, glad you found your answer!