# Go pointer to interface is not null

Tags: go, interface

Can someone provide some explanation about this code behaviour:
https://play.golang.org/p/_TjQhthHl3

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyError struct{}
func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return "some error"
}

func main() {
    var err error
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("[OK] err is nil ...")
    }else{
        fmt.Println("[KO] err is NOT nil...")
    }
    isNil(err)


    var err2 *MyError
    if err2 == nil {
        fmt.Println("[OK] err2 is nil ...")
    }else{
        fmt.Println("[KO] err2 is NOT nil...")
    }
    isNil(err2)
}

func isNil(err error){
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("[OK] ... still nil")
    }else{
        fmt.Println("[KO] .. why not nil?")
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
[OK] err is nil ...
[OK] ... still nil
[OK] err2 is nil ...
[KO] .. why err2 not nil?
```

I found this post [Check for nil and nil interface in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476349/check-for-nil-and-nil-interface-in-go) but I still don't get it...

Comment: Also see the FAQ: https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`error` is a built-in interface, and `*MyError` implements that interface. Even though the value of `err2` is nil, when you pass it to `isNil`, the function gets a non-nil interface value. That value contains information about the type (`*MyError`) and the value itself, which is a nil pointer.

If you try printing `err` in `isNil`, you'll see that in the second case, you get "some error" even though `err2` is nil. This demonstrates why `err` is not nil in that case (it has to contain the type information).

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding your `var err2 *MyError` definition is generating a pointer to the struct definition and NOT an actual instantiated object.

Comment: It does not explain why it's not `nil`. It declares a pointer and initialises it with the `nil `value.

Answer (score 1):

In Go interface types are represented by a structure with 2 fields: one denotes its actual type and the other is a pointer to the value.

It means that an interface value is never equal to `nil` unless the value you passed is actually a `nil` value.

Relevant and good talk: [GopherCon 2016: Francesc Campoy - Understanding nil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynoY2xz-F8s)